# Finding all the invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a method for find all the $j$-dimensional invariant subspaces for a given linear operator, without considering its Jordan form?

And if such thing exist, could you please show it to me through this simple example?

$$ T: \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^3 \\ A = \left[ T\right]_B = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&-3\\0&1&3\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Isn't this the same as asking for the eigenspace for $\lambda = 1$?

Comment: I'm asking in general. The given operator is just for exemplify. Besides, i'm concerned about non-trivial invariant subspaces, in this case, of dimension 1 and 2.

Comment: In general, it's the same as finding eigenvectors (but not necessarily finding the full Jordan form)